# How to handle request being redirected to different api version?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a controller inside my .net core api with a defined version so that I can access my restful endpoint like `/api/v2.0/controller/`. The issue is that also requests with different versions like this `/api/v99.0/controller/` will be redirected to the first one, I would like to return a 404 not found error.

`The controller is decorated like this:`

```
[Authorize]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
```

`And the action is decorated with just this`

```
  [HttpGet]
```

Comment: AFAIK ,by default , it will show error `InvalidApiVersion` error , could you please show more details to reproduce ?